# Django Endless Pagination Twitter Style Ajax breaks on another Ajax call

Tags: python, django, jquery, pagination, django-endless-pagination

I am using Django Endless Pagination. Everything works fine as per the Read the Docs, except that when I do an Ajax search, which is an ajax form search on rendered paginated scrolled results, the code breaks.

As I understand, this is because the main template is what gets compiled first, and none of the template that throws the json dump (ajax search results) is not compiled. What is the work around so that both ajax search, and ajax endless scroll can work.

My views.py main template view

http://pastebin.com/TjkMbQdp

Function which provides Ajax Search
http://pastebin.com/xE3rk4v1

I use multiple templates to generate the search results. The Ajax search works very well on its own, and the Ajax Endless Page Scroll using Django endless pagination also works perfectly.

However both together fails, if you try scrolling it on an Ajax searched result, it fails...

What is the logical steps to fix this...

Comment: @rmartins said : "Did you find a solution? I'm with a similar problem."

Comment: @martins No. I finally wrote my own paginator, connected with my search function to close the project. Scrapped endless pagination